What algorithms for matching webpage similarity?
My task is to create a redirect map from old to the new site, based on matched similarity of urls, titles, descriptions and content embeddings.
What algorithm would you recommend for such task?

The first issue is formally defining when two web pages are similar.
For example, using different CSS style sheets on the (otherwise) same HTML page will give very different appearance for web pages.
And web browsers like dillo, or links, or firefox will have different behavior. Since some of them have a Javascript interpreter, and others don't (and since JavaScript has different and incompatible implementations the behavior would be different).
PS. Very probably your problem can be proved equivalent to the Halting Problem.
